XMorpher model for DMIR - dataset problem
I'm trying to run a GitHub project XMorpher (https://github.com/Solemoon/XMorpher/tree/main) but the writer did not give the right dataset? In code he used:
 train_labeled_unlabeled_dir = 'data/train_labeled_unlabeled'
 train_unlabeled_unlabeled_dir = 'data/train_unlabeled_unlabeled'
 test_labeled_labeled_dir = 'data/test'

but in reality data folder contains only 0_1.mat file, which - when opened in Matlab - includes 2 variables:
fix_img  # size: 144x144x128 (int16)
mov_img  # size: 144x144x128 (int16)

Due to 5308416 bytes that one image contains I'm not able to see values of variables.. Does anyone knows any other way of running this model or which other dataset can I use?
Thank you for any answers.
